# twig format date (displaying 1 instead of 01)

Tags: symfony, date, format, twig

currently I'm using this setting:

```
twig:
    date:
        format: d. m. Y
        interval_format: '%%d days'
```

How do I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig uses the same formatter at supported by [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

To get the day of the month without the leading zero you can use `j`.